# Links in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, hyperlink

im have a page. The url page is:

> mydomain/web/app_dev.php/Common/homePage

And i need create a link. The href of anchor must be link to

> mydomain/web/app_dev.php/Menus/seleccionarMenu

The action of the second link, is in other controller, in other bundle.
How make this ?.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `path()`:

```
<a href="{{ path( routeName ) }}">Some Text</a>
```

`routeName` follows basic Symfony naming conventions, or explicit name if given in route annotation.

Comment: thanks for reply. I try puth `path(/Menus/seleccionarMenu)` but an error appear: `"Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/Menus/seleccionarMenu" as such route does not exist."`. I my app/config/routing have this: `@MenusBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` and in the bundle routing have: `pattern: /Menus/seleccionarMenu`.

Comment: You have to write the name of the route, and not the actual path. run `php app/console router:debug` from command line in order to get such name.

Comment: the command return `seleccion_menu ANY ANY ANY  /Menus/seleccionarMenu`

Comment: `seleccion_menu` is your route name - write `path( 'seleccion_menu' )` then.